# two identical assertThrows lines behave differently

Tags: java, class, exception, junit5

I have the following identical assertThrows line in two tests:

```
Assertions.assertThrows(HttpServerErrorException.BadGateway.class, (Executable) restTemplate.postForEntity(builder.toUriString(), request, String.class));
```

One of the tests passes and the other gives this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity cannot be cast to class org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable (org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity and org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Does anyone know why this could be the case? Why am I able to cast ResponseEntity to class Executable for one test and not the other?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of debug evaluation of what you are trying to cast in both cases? I feel like the test passing is returning null and that would explain why you are able to cast it

Answer (score 0):

Please try so:

```
  Assertions.assertThrows(HttpServerErrorException.BadGateway.class, () -> restTemplate.postForEntity(builder.toUriString(), request, String.class));
```

For now you make it so:
`public <T> ResponseEntity<T> postForEntity(...)` returns `ResponseEntity` and then you cast it to `Executable` interface smth like:

```
ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity = new ResponseEtity<>(...);
Executable ex = (Executable) responseEntity; // ClassCastException
```

`Executable` is a functional interface and you should pass lambda parameter, i.e. implementation of `Executable` interface in `assertThrows` method.

Comment: The issue has been sorted another way as another class was causing the request object not to contain the right contents, but this information is very valuable to me understanding things and is likely to be useful down the line. Thank you loads!

Comment: In any case, you should not do casting there but use lambda. You are casting `Executable` to `ResponseEntity` although neither `ResponseEntity` nor its superclasses implement this interface. You code in one test method works only because your `postForEntity(...)` method returns `null`.